# Проверка правильности IP адреса на C++

Tags: c++, ip, ip-address

Дан IP адрес. Необходимо проверить его правильность (все числа в диапазоне 0-255, числа разделены точками, количество чисел: 4, точек: 3).
Помогите исправить ввод адреса (В строке циклом находятся цифры и записываются в 1 переменную. При окончании строки точка записывается в массив separators, а число - в nums) и проверку (функция is_valid). Ввод без строки реализовать не получилось.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
//#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class IPAddress{
    int nums[3];
    char separators[3];
public:
    void input();
    bool is_valid();
};

void IPAddress::input(){
    char c[101]={};
    char sym='0';
    int j=0, num=0, ia;
    cin.getline(c,101);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        //ia=sym-'0';
        while(true!=false){
            sym=c[j];
            ia=sym-'0';
            if(isdigit(sym)!=0){
                num*=10;
                num+=ia;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if(c[j]=='.') separators[i]='.';
        j++;
        num=0;
    }
}

bool IPAddress::is_valid(){
    bool err=true;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if(nums[i]>255||nums[i]<0) err=false;
        if(i!=3){
            if(separators[i]!='.') err=false;
        }
    }
    return err;
}

int main() {
    IPAddress ip;
    ip.input();
    if(ip.is_valid()==true) cout << 1;
    else cout << 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А просто проверить, что `addr == InetPtoN(InetNtoP(addr))` - не? *Необходимо проверить его правильность (все числа в диапазоне 0-255, числа разделены точками, количество чисел: 4, точек: 3).* Написанное не является критерием ПРАВИЛЬНОСТИ IP-адреса.